# Not Getting the Shape Right in DocumentDb Select

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to get only the person's membership info i.e. ID, name and committee memberships in a SELECT query. This is my object:

```
{
   "id": 123,
   "name": "John Smith",
   "memberships": [
      {
          "id": 789,
          "name": "U.S. Congress",
          "yearElected": 2012,
          "state": "California",
          "committees": [
             {
                 "id": 444,
                 "name": "Appropriations Comittee",
                 "position": "Member"
             },
             {
                 "id": 555,
                 "name": "Armed Services Comittee",
                 "position": "Chairman"
             },
             {
                 "id": 678,
                 "name": "Veterans' Affairs Comittee",
                 "position": "Member"
             }
          ]
      }
   ]
}
```

In this example, John Smith is a member of the U.S. Congress and three committees in it.

The result that I'm trying to get should look like this. Again, this is the "DESIRED RESULT":

```
{
   "id": 789,
   "name": "U.S. Congress",
   "committees": [
      {
         "id": 444,
         "name": "Appropriations Committee",
         "position": "Member"
      },
      {
         "id": 555,
         "name": "Armed Services Committee",
         "position": "Chairman"
      },
      {
         "id": 678,
         "name": "Veterans' Affairs Committee",
         "position": "Member"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here's my SQL query:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, 
[ 
    {
        "id": c.id,
        "name": c.name,
        "position": c.position
    }
] AS committees
FROM a 
JOIN m IN a.memberships
JOIN c IN m.committees
WHERE a.id = "123"
```

I'm getting the following results which is correct but the shape is not right. I'm getting the same membership 3 times. Here's what I'm getting which is NOT the desired result:

```
[
 {
   "id": 789,
   "name": "U.S. Congress",
   "committees":[
      {
         "id": 444,
         "name": "Appropriations Committee",
         "position": "Member"
      }
   ]
 },
 {
   "id": 789,
   "name": "U.S. Congress",
   "committees":[
      {
         "id": 555,
         "name": "Armed Services Committee",
         "position": "Chairman"
      }
   ]
 },
 {
   "id": 789,
   "name": "U.S. Congress",
   "committees":[
      {
         "id": 678,
         "name": "Veterans' Affairs Committee",
         "position": "Member"
      }
   ]
 }
]
```

As you can see here, the "U.S. Congress" membership is repeated 3 times.

The following SQL query gets me exactly what I want in Azure Query Explorer but when I pass it as the query in my code -- using DocumentDb SDK -- I don't get any of the details for the committees. I simply get blank results for committee ID, name and position. I do, however, get the membership data i.e. "U.S. Congress", etc. Here's that SQL query:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, m.committees AS committees 
FROM c 
JOIN m IN c.memberhips 
WHERE c.id = 123
```

I'm including the code that makes the DocumentDb call. I'm including the code with our internal comments to help clarify their purpose:

First the ReadQuery function that we call whenever we need to read something from DocumentDb:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReadQuery<T>(string collectionId, string sql, Dictionary<string, object> parameterNameValueCollection)
{
   // Prepare collection self link
   var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_dbName, collectionId);

   // Prepare query
   var query = getQuery(sql, parameterNameValueCollection);

   // Creates the query and returns IQueryable object that will be executed by the calling function
   var result = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collectionLink, query, null);

   return await result.QueryAsync();
}
```

The following function prepares the query -- with any parameters:

```
protected SqlQuerySpec getQuery(string sql, Dictionary<string, object> parameterNameValueCollection)
{
   // Declare query object
   SqlQuerySpec query = new SqlQuerySpec();

   // Set query text
   query.QueryText = sql;

   // Convert parameters received in a collection to DocumentDb paramters
   if (parameterNameValueCollection != null && parameterNameValueCollection.Count > 0)
   {
      //  Go through each item in the parameters collection and process it
      foreach (var item in parameterNameValueCollection)
      {
         query.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter($"@{item.Key}", item.Value));
      }
   }

   return query;
}
```

This function makes async call to DocumentDb:

```
public async static Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
   var docQuery = query.AsDocumentQuery();

   // Batches gives us the ability to read data in chunks in an asyc fashion.
   // If we use the ToList<T>() LINQ method to read ALL the data, the call will synchronous which is why we prefer the batches approach.
   var batches = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();

   do
   {
      // Actual call is made to the backend DocumentDb database
      var batch = await docQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
      batches.Add(batch);
   }

   while (docQuery.HasMoreResults);

  // Because batches are collections of collections, we use the following line to merge all into a single collection.
  var docs = batches.SelectMany(b => b);

  // Return data
  return docs;
}
```

Comment: is `JOIN m IN c.memberhips ` in the last code block a typo here or in your code? Or are you just adding to your politicians girth? ;)

Comment: @MichaelB That's a typo. It's correct in the code. The main issue seems to be that if I just select a subdocument like SELECT m.committees, I don't seem to get any data when I make the call in my code. However, if I run the same SELECT query in Query Explorer on Azure Portal, I see all the data I need. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updated my original post. All the code provided in the question is correct and works. I was having a problem because I was using aliases in the SELECT query and as a result some properties were not binding to my domain object.

The code provided in the question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I just write a demo to test with your query and I can get the expected result, check the snapshot below. So I think that query is correct, you've mentioned that you don't seem to get any data when you make the call in my code, would you mind share your code? Perhaps there are some mistakes in you code. Anyway, here is my test just for your reference and hope it helps.

[image]

**Query used**:

```
SELECT m.id AS membershipId, m.name AS membershipNameName, m.committees AS committees 
FROM c 
JOIN m IN c.memberships 
WHERE c.id = "123"
```

**Code here is very simple, sp_db.innerText represents a span which I used to show the result in my test page**:

```
var docs = client.CreateDocumentQuery("dbs/" + databaseId + "/colls/" + collectionId,
"SELECT m.id AS membershipId, m.name AS membershipName, m.committees AS committees " +
"FROM c " +
"JOIN m IN c.memberships " +
"WHERE c.id = \"123\"");
        foreach (var doc in docs)
        {
            sp_db.InnerText += doc;
        }
```

I think maybe there are some typos in the query you specified in **client.CreateDocumentQuery()** which makes the result to be none, it's better to provide the code for us, then we can help check it.

***Updates:***
Just tried your code and still I can get the expected result. One thing I found is that when I specified the where clause like **"where c.id = \"123\""**, it gets the result:
[image]

However, if you didn't make the escape and just use "where c.id = 123", this time you get nothing. I think this could be a reason. You can verify whether you have ran into this scenario.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just added our code at the bottom of the original post. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Sam I just tried with your code and it still works, see the snapshots I updated in my reply. I think it might be related to the \" in where clause, but since you didn't share what the sql query looks like in your code, I am not 100% sure about this. I suggest you check my update and then verify it.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I resolved the issue. Turns out it, I was having this issue because I was using aliases for two of the "fields" in my Select statement. As a result, they didn't match the property names in my class. So it was a binding issue!

Comment: @sam thanks for sharing it, glad to hear you have resolved the issue :)

Comment: @Sam - please post your solution properly as an answer, and then you can be properly marked as accepted.